# How to get the values of an OBJECT or ROWTYPE dynamically (Reflection) in Oracle PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to take a ROWTYPE, RECORD, or OBJECT type and dynamically convert it to a single string representation.
I want to do this dynamically.

***Update:*** Doing this for an OBJECT type now working thanks to Justin Cave's feedback.

**Example Data:**

```
ID | VAL
---------
1  | BOB
```

**Desired Output:**

```
ID=1, VAL=BOB
```

**Error Received:**

```
ORA-06550: line 7, column 25:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'TO_STRING'
ORA-06550: line 7, column 4:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

**What I have so Far (Doesn't loop through columns yet.):**

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION to_string (
    ip_anydata in out anydata --note the "out" - this is required for the "piecewise"
)
RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
   lv_typecode PLS_INTEGER;
   lv_anytype anytype;
BEGIN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('[Expected='||dbms_types.typecode_object||', Actual='||ip_anydata.getType(lv_anytype)||']');
   --Get the typecode, and the ANYTYPE
   lv_typecode := ip_anydata.getType(lv_anytype);

   --Check that it's really an object
   IF lv_typecode = dbms_types.typecode_object
   THEN
      --If it is an object, find the first item
      DECLARE
         lv_first_attribute_typecode pls_integer;
         lv_aname          varchar2(32767);
         lv_result         pls_integer;
         lv_varchar        varchar2(32767);
         --Variables we don't really care about, but need for function output
         lv_prec           pls_integer; 
         lv_scale          pls_integer;
         lv_len            pls_integer;
         lv_csid           pls_integer;
         lv_csfrm          pls_integer;
         lv_attr_elt_type  anytype;
      BEGIN
         lv_first_attribute_typecode := lv_anytype.getAttrElemInfo(
            pos            => 1, --First attribute
            prec           => lv_prec,
            scale          => lv_scale,
            len            => lv_len,
            csid           => lv_csid,
            csfrm          => lv_csfrm,
            attr_elt_type  => lv_attr_elt_type,
            aname          => lv_aname
         );

         --Check typecode of attribute
         IF lv_first_attribute_typecode = dbms_types.typecode_varchar2
         THEN
            --Now that we've verified the type, get the actual value.
            ip_anydata.piecewise;
            lv_result := ip_anydata.getVarchar2(c => lv_varchar);

            --DEBUG: Print the attribute name, in case you're curious
            --dbms_output.put_line('lv_aname: '||lv_aname);
            RETURN lv_aname||'='||lv_varchar;
         ELSE
            raise_application_error(-20000, 'Unexpected 1st Attribute Typecode: '||lv_first_attribute_typecode);
         END IF;
      END;
   ELSE
       raise_application_error(-20000, 'Unexpected Typecode: '||lv_typecode);
   END IF;
END;
/
```

**Scenario#1 - Select INTO w/ ROWTYPE:**

```sql
DECLARE
   lv_cv dual%ROWTYPE;
   lv_str VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('-----------------------------');
   SELECT * INTO lv_cv FROM dual WHERE ROWNUM <= 1;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(to_string(lv_cv));
END;
/
```

**Scenario#2 - FETCH INTO w/ Cursor ROWTYPE:**

```sql
DECLARE
   CURSOR cv_cur IS SELECT * FROM dual WHERE ROWNUM <= 1;
   lv_cv cv_cur%ROWTYPE;
   lv_str VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('-----------------------------');
   OPEN cv_cur;
   FETCH cv_cur INTO lv_cv;
   CLOSE cv_cur;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(to_string(lv_cv));
END;
/
```

**Scenario#3 - Regular OBJECT:** *(Updated)*

```sql
DECLARE
   lv_cv T_CODE_VAL_REC := T_CODE_VAL_REC('BOB', 5);
   lv_str VARCHAR2(32767);
   lv_any ANYDATA;
BEGIN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('-----------------------------');
   lv_any := sys.anydata.ConvertObject(lv_cv);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(to_string(lv_any));
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
   pts2_test_valitation_util.fail(999, CHR(10)||CHR(10)||'Unexpected Error:'||CHR(10)||SQLERRM||CHR(10)||DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE);
END;
/
```

Comment: I don't have high hopes that this is possible.  If you want `to_string` to accept an `anydata`, you'd first have to convert your parameter to an `anydata`.  For the object type, that's easy enough `dbms_output.put_line(to_string(sys.anydata.ConvertObject(lv_cv)))`.  For the non-SQL types, though, you'd need to do a piecewise construction of the `anydata` https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/t_anydat.htm#i1001265 which would likely defeat the purpose of trying to build this sort of generic code.

Comment: Are you actually looking for something that will handle both record/rowtype *and* object types; or do you really only want to take any object type? (I suspect the former but the wording is slightly ambiguous). The object type is easy enough as Justin said. For rowtype you could perhaps have an overloaded function that takes a cursor and manipulates it with `dbms_sql` instead, but not if your starting point is a record rather than the query that populated it.

Comment: I want something that will handle both record/rowtype and object types. I'm OK w/ creating a separate function for each, though.

Comment: Verified that scenario#3 now works thanks to feedback from Justin. Note that you have to store the ANYDATA object in a veriable in order to pass it to the function since it has IN OUT criteria.

Comment: Forgot to correct that in the question. Thanks. Fixed now.

Comment: Did you manage to make this work for scenario #1 / #2?

Comment: Unfortunately, only scenario #3 works.

Comment: I don't know of any way to do this for a record. You could use PL/Scope to determine its structure. That would give you field names dynamically. (But only if production code was compiled with all_identifiers:on. But you would still need to be able to evaluate the record's fields and I am stuck there.