# Oracle Trigger: How to put OLD and NEW values as JSON for multiple tables

Tags: json, database, oracle, triggers, audit

I'm wondering if this is possible in **Oracle 12g** to make a procedure that will be called on update from triggers on multiple tables with different columns.
From my understanding I got two values **OLD** and **NEW**. I'm making trigger that work **AFTER UPDATE** & **FOR EACH ROW**. Does this possible to send whole row ( variables **:OLD** or **:NEW**) to some function like **JSON_OBJECT** or etc. which will parse row and produce output that can be stored in some audit table?

**Main reason** for such needs is to not keep in every trigger their own list of columns names for table. Because it different and every change in every table structure will affect trigger.

Or maybe **I'm wrong** and you **can suggest** how to properly solve this?

For test cases I have something like this:

```
AUDIT_TBL (ID, TABLE_NAME,OLD_JSON,NEW_JSON,DATE);
TABLE1 (ID,KEY,VALUE);
TABLE2 (ID,NAME,SURNAME,KEY);
TABLE3 (KEY,COLUMN1,CLOMUNT2,COLUMN3);
```

I was planning to have trigger on **TABLE1**,**TABLE2**,**TABLE3** that will run some procedure with parameters as row (**:OLD** or **:NEW**), will get a result and put it into **AUDIT_TBL**.

Any suggestions or ideas how to do this properly and without blood?

Comment: The :old and :new pseudo-records in triggers cannot be passed to subprograms as records or %rowtypes

Comment: A procedure argument can't accept an arbitrary record/rowtype though, which seems to be what you're looking for. The data type and structure has to be known at compile time. [Slightly related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39795761/266304). Why is updating a trigger when its table changes a problem?

Comment: In this case this meant that this will be no way to use same trigger code multiple times? Every trigger will need to have own columns dictionary?  2. Problem will be to change trigger to reflect changes. If Next version of Table1 will have 1 more columns - this will need to edit trigger and add new column to JSON.